# Need help understanding nesting

Tags: html, css, nested

I am having trouble with getting a HTML website to display the way I want. I have made a banner and a nav bar, but I'm having a hard time when trying to add anything below the nav; it either covers the banner or gets covered by it.

This is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Home: Old Barber </title>
</head>
<body id="body"><link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="header"> Welcome </header>
        <div id="bannerHolder">
            <div class="banner">
                OLD BARBER
            </div>
            <nav id="nav">
                <a href="test_template.html"> Home </a>
                <a href="test_template.html"> Products </a>
                <a href="test_template.html"> About </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://www.open.edu/openlearn/ocw/pluginfile.php/1654608/mod_oucontent/oucontent/93155/8a822f73/b6b08556/mse_s6_figure_3.jpg" alt="Barber" class="img"></img>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Shop</div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
/* Imported fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merienda:wght@700&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Italianno&display=swap');

#wrapper {
    background: orange;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#bannerHolder {
    background: #aaa;
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
}

#bannerHolder .banner {
    background-image: url(https://p0.zoon.ru/d/d/5ce4efe774cfee5d9265c8ee_5d6e753f1d26b.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
    font-size: 800%;
    height: 200%;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
}

#body{
    background-color: gray;
}

#nav{
    background-color: orange;
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0.5%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#h1{
    font-family: 'Italianno', cursive;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}

.img{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
    background-color: orange;
}

.container:hover .overlay{
    opacity: 1;
}

.text{
    color: white;
    font-size: larger;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**: under is the result after removing the `position: absolute;` from the header. This, however, also alters the way in which I'd like the page to be displayed; which is that the banner, nav etc. is supposed to fill the page on the left, right and top.

[image: html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that You have

`<div id="wrapper">` and `<div class="container">` below.

`<div id="wrapper">` - has `position: absolute` as a style.

Position absolute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position:

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is
> created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative
> to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed
> relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is
> determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
>
> This value creates a new stacking context when the value of z-index is
> not auto. The margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not collapse
> with other margins.

That means that Your `wrapper` div, creates no space, so `container` div ignores its position.

Try to remove `position: absolute` from Your header.

**Edit**:

Sorry for late answer

```
#wrapper {
    background: orange;
    text-align: center;
}

#bannerHolder .banner {
    background-image: url(https://p0.zoon.ru/d/d/5ce4efe774cfee5d9265c8ee_5d6e753f1d26b.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
    font-size: 800%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
}

body {
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Edited CSS for header would look something like this. What I've done is I removed the height parameter of `#bannerHolder`. This height was defining the height of 100px for `bannerHolder`, however the height of the inside elements of `bannerHolder` was bigger, so there was an overlap. I also removed some unused CSS properties.

Also for banner to fill the whole space - the common pattern is to set `padding: 0; margin: 0;` for body tag. I often start my projects with this set-up:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oamx38y6/36/